# Dynamically switch Microsoft.Speech profiles

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, speech

I'm developing an AI to act as a personal assistant which gets Voice Commands from input,Matches them against a preloaded Grammar and do some jobs based on the result. Everything is fine except as I use Microsoft.Speech, It gets used to my voice. So it gets better and better recognizing my voice but it doesn't recognize my wife's voice at all!
So I guess my options are:
1.Dynamically switch profiles.
2.Go with another library.
What should I do?
Any other suggestion would be nice.
I can inject any other library into my Robot if u know a better one.

Comment: For anyone who reads this post, I couldn't find the answer myself. But I found an alternative which is using https://wit.ai/ free speech recognition service. I will let you know more about it as I complete the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, I finally used wit.ai speech recognition. It works fine for me at the moment, Except it takes a couple of seconds until it shows me the result. I'm going to use google speech engine as well. I'll let you know if it works better than wit.ai